# GTK-2 error when installing Glassfish plugin for Eclipse on Fedora 16 64-bit

Tags: fedora, gtk, eclipse

I have Eclipse running fine on my Fedora 16.  I was following [these instructions](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/) to install the Glassfish Tools Bundle for Eclipse (which has to be done outside Eclipse through its own installer) and, after I went through the installer successfully, the next step was to launch the eclipse launcher in the plugin directory (so not the regular Eclipse launcher). I got the following error:

```
> ./eclipse

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",

(eclipse:2300): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "clearlooks",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

That was reported in the terminal.  The GUI that popped up briefly said there is also an error log file under ~/workspace/.metadata/.log, which has the following:

```
!SESSION 2012-09-27 22:18:52.512 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
java.version=1.6.0_16
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -pluginCustomization plugin_customization.ini -showsplash org.eclipse.platform
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -pluginCustomization plugin_customization.ini -showsplash org.eclipse.platform

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher 4 0 2012-09-27 22:19:01.715
!MESSAGE The installable unit org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt.translated_host_properties is missing the filename property.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-09-27 22:19:07.181
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3555 or swt-pi-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
!SESSION 2012-09-27 22:22:17.706 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
java.version=1.6.0_16
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -pluginCustomization plugin_customization.ini -showsplash org.eclipse.platform
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -pluginCustomization plugin_customization.ini -showsplash org.eclipse.platform
```

I found [this site](http://plosquare.blogspot.com/2008/12/gtk-warning-wrong-elf-class-elfclass64.html) but I can't follow the instructions there to save my life.  All I understand is that GTK-2 needs some 32-bit libs even though the system is 64-bit but it is trying to open 64-bit ones.

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, that Glassfish Tools Bundle you linked to is a) just a collection of Eclipse 3.51 and Glassfish v3, b) compiled for 32-bit, and c) ancient.

Rather than follow ancient instructions that have little or no bearing on current 64-bit distributions, why not search for packages for Eclipse and Glassfish for Fedora 16?  Or if they are not available anywhere, try packages for Fedora 17 or 18, download the SRPMS and backport them to Fedora 16 (i.e. compile the source packages on F16).

(i'm no expert on Fedora packages, but a quick google search makes me suspect that glassfish v3 is available for F18 but not F16...so backporting the srpm would be a viable option).

That may sound like a lot of work, but it'll probably be easier and a lot less work than stuffing around trying to get ancient instructions for 32-bit foreign (i.e. non-Fedora) binaries working on F16.  More importantly, it'll be a lot less fragile, being compiled for the exact environment you're using it in, so less likely to break on any future upgrade.

---

BTW, as a rule of thumb, if you're using a package-managed distribution like Fedora (or RHEL, Centos, Debian, Ubuntu and others) it's a good idea to view any web page that gives instructions for installing that start something like "downlaod this binary tarball from this location" or even "download the source..." with deep suspicion.  It's almost certainly out-dated and/or written by someone who doesn't have a clue about how package managers work and doesn't understand the mess that can be caused by bypassing them....often by a programmer who just wants it working right NOW (because they've got urgent work that needs doing) and doesn't want to think about how it might break in future.

Package managers are not an obstruction to be worked around, they are a valuable tool to help you manage your system(s)...and the more programs you work with, and the more systems you look after, the more valuable the tool becomes.

Sometimes there is no other choice but to go outside the package manager....but that should always be the **last resort** (after backporting and even trying to build your own packages has already failed)....and even when it is unavoidably necessary, you should use something like [stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) to manage the installation in /usr/local.

Comment: i think the binary download from the site (i.e. not in yum repo) is all that is available

Comment: Both Glassfish and Eclipse are available separately (even packaged for various distros).  The Glassfish Plugin for Eclipse is also available separately - the link on the site you mentioned is a dead link (it probably got abandoned when Oracle bought Sun and most of Sun's developers left), but a newer version appears to be available at http://glassfishplugins.java.net/

Comment: Thanks, Craig.  I will check it out when I get home after work today.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions from the original post were stale.  [Here](http://glassfishplugins.java.net) are the up to date ones.  Thanks @Craig Sanders